# Http request doesn't work on the release version

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic-framework, release

An ionic app doesn't make http requests for the release version, but it works fine for the debug ones.
Any idea?! I tried the CSP but nothing was changed.

Comment: Are you using `https`?

Comment: Yes I'm using https!

Comment: Then there is some issue in SSL certificate. Check if you have valid SSL certificate.

Comment: Thank you..... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you use a valid SSL certificate and SSL configuration on the server side, for the case of apache2, and SSL wildcard, make sure to put the correct values for the following keys:

```
SSLCertificateFile
SSLCertificateKeyFile
SSLCertificateChainFile
```